# Desktop icons keep changing position

Tags: windows-7, desktop-icons

My icons keep changing position after I play a video game that's set to another resolution or when I plug the laptop onto a TV/projector (basically different resolution will cause it).

How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to stop this irritating behavior but as a remedy you can install [DesktopOK](http://www.freewarefiles.com/DesktopOK_program_40113.html) and save the icon layout.