# Desktop icon layout keeps changing when resuming from standby

Tags: windows-8.1, icons, desktop-icons

I use my laptop for college and as a result, it's moved around a lot. When the lid is shut I have it going to standby, but however ***every*** time I resume it, my desktop layout changes.

It goes from this:
[image: before]

to this:
[image: after]

I have `auto-arrange icons` unchecked in the desktop properties, so this couldn't be causing it.
I've done some more digging, and it also happens when restarting Windows Explorer (killing it via Task Manager and starting it again via 'New Task').

This doesn't happen when exiting games that I play with a lower screen resolution, so the changing of the screen resolution won't be causing it.

What could be causing this, and how can I stop it from arranging my icons (so badly, I might add)?

I want to keep my laptop free from junk, so I do not want any 'solutions' such as programs that remember my desktop's icon layout (as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/329953/desktop-icons-keep-changing-position)).

The laptop is a Lenovo Flex 2 15, equipped with a Nividia 820M GPU- all drivers are up-to-date.

Comment: Are there any external monitors involved in this?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No, there isn't. The last time this laptop was connected to an external monitor was my TV via HDMI around a fortnight ago.

Comment: If you log in as another user, does it behave the same way?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Had to create a new account, but logging in as a new user does not have this issue.

Comment: Then it's something specific to your user's settings. Do a [Clean boot](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1656449/clean-boot-windows.html) to disable all non-MS start-ups and services, and then log in as yourself again.  Does it behave any differently?